# How do I generate multiple charts from the same template for different inputs / scenarios

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using Excel, and have some basic VBA / Macro knowledge. I have a reasonable large data set that updates each week. From that Im using a series of Index/match to generate a table that is 40 columns (dates) by 4 rows ( time series data) for a specific product. I have 15-20 different products, which often change. This 4x40 table is then used to generate a chart. Using this manually I can select the product with a drop down box (Data validation), my index / matches pull the correct data into the 4x40 table, and the chart for that product is shown. But I'd like to have a macro that will generate the chart for product 1, copy and paste as an image to a word doc, then do the same for product 2, and 3, and so on, and then save the word doc as a pdf for distribution.

An option would be to create 15-20 of the 4x40 tables, and 15-20 of the charts, and then just copy / paste all of them, but it would become a nightmare to maintain as the products change, and if formatting changes are requested, more than likely.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your exact worksheet is hard to give an exact piece of code. However I made a workbook with a requirement similar to this recently.

As an outline of an answer you could consider using a loop to loop through your list of 15 - 20 products placing each of them within the cell which you currently have your data validation (ensuring you have removed any validation first) this would then update the index matches and also your chart. 
Within that loop you could include some code to save the sheet as a pdf before moving on to the next product (or place the chart on a separate worksheet and reference this explicitly).

e.g if your validation is in cell A1 worksheet "Table" and your list of products is A2:A20 worksheet "Products" something like this will get you some of the way;

```
Sub save_charts()

Dim i As Long
Dim path As String
Dim product_name As String
Dim ws_name As String
Dim file_name As String

i = 2
path = Application.DefaultFilePath

Do Until Worksheets("Products").Cells(i, 1).Value = ""

If Worksheets("Products").Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
product_name = Worksheets("Table").Cells(1, 1).Value
ws_name = product_name & " Chart"
file_name = path & "\" & ws_name
Worksheets("Table").Cells(1, 1).Value = Worksheets("Products").Cells(i, 1).Value
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        file_name, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
        True

End If

i = i + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

I am aware that you mentioned copying this into word before exporting as pdf? Is this a requirement? As this code just uses Excel's native export to pdf functionality.

I hope this helps.

Cheers.

Comment: Mike P, that's exactly what I need, thank you. Yes, exporting from Excel straight to pdf is fine and works well. Last question is getting the charts not to split accross pages on the pdf / getting the page breaks in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that will automatically generate all 20 charts with each refresh with 0 vba would be to do the following steps 1 time:
1. Create a pivot table and pivot table chart you need for a given product, eg filter it on a single product code, create the basic chart, put off formatting for now. The source data for this pivot table needs to include the data for all 20 products

2. In the source data for step 1, add another column called FilterID and set this by formula so that 1 = the data for the first product; 2, the second; 3, etc.
3. Go back to step 1 pivot table and add FilterID as a pivot filter, set it to 1, so only the first product appears on the chart
4. Format the chart to taste
5. Now copy the worksheet containing the pivot table and pivot chart 20 times
6. Increment the FilterID on each copy

The only vba you need at this point is to cycle through each worksheet with a valid chart and save to pdf